# how to count the rows in a table using t-sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
S.NO    MATEL     PRODUCT
1       STEEL     TANDEM
5       IRON      COMMUTER
7       FIBER     TOURING
```

I Need to count the rows in the above table and insert in next rows without changing names of matel and product.

```
8        STEEL     TANDEM
12       IRON      COMMUTER
14       FIBER     TOURING
```

Can you guys help me in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable
SELECT  no + maxno, matel, product
FROM    mytable
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  MAX(no) maxno
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
```

If `no` is an identity, you'd need to issue

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON
```

prior to running the query and set if back to off afterwards.

Comment: from the 4th row i need to insert the same data but s.no must be incresed according to first three rows ...

Comment: Thank you...but its easy if we count the row and insert the values in to 4th row and continuing using loop....but what should i need to use the function to count the rows and declaring that rows to a varaible is it possible in T-sql ???

Comment: @Dood: yes it is, though it's an inferior solution from all points of view. Why would you need a loop for this?

Comment: :if s.no@i ig given as 45 it should print the rows up to s.no 45 simultaniously it should print remaining matel and product.For the rows 4 5 6 i have given S.no is 14 ???

Comment: @Dood: I haven't understood anything here.